# How do I "save" the final sum outside a loop?

Tags: loops, python-3.x, scope, tuples, partition

```
s=0
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(6):
        for k in range(9):
            if 1*i+2*j+3*k == 17:
                s=s+i+j+k
            else:
```

print(s) # prints a positive integer, not 0 as it had before

## first problem solved

Is there a more elegant way to sum over a finite set of tuples
where the components of those tuples are constrained by some system
of equations & inequations, than manually writing out each condition
given by those equations as if-else statements inside loops?

Ideally, eventually, I would like to make the length, n, of my tuples itself a variable, which I can then set at runtime.  I would then like to sum a function, f(x(1),...,x(n)) over all n-tuples of nonnegative integers (x(1),...,x(n)) which are constrained in various ways, most commonly, sum of i*x(i) = m, for some given m (partitions of m).

Ultimately, the hypothetical goal is programming Gregory Egorychev's magnificent generalization of the Lagrange Inversion Formula (LIF) to systems of multiples equations & dependent variables.

Thanks for the two responses so far.

Comment: If that's python (which I guess) you should tag it that way

Comment: did you mean printing 's' outside the loop but after it? it's in the current scope so its not an error. what did you mean by "saving" it?